# How to set default value of a text column based on another choice column

Tags: list-form

I have a choice column [Category] followed by text column [details] in the same list. While adding new item, by default, I want the value in [details] to be the same as what I selected in [Category] with the option for the user to change (override) it. Specifying default calculated value as [Category] is not working (shows as error). I am using SharePoint online (Office 365 E1). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A default value formula cannot reference another column because the list form does not support a dynamic recalculation of the default formula.

If you need to set a default value based on another column, and still have that user editable, you can use workflow, or use Javascript / jQuery to set the field.